# HTTP 504 Errors in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have some users are experiencing HTTP 504 errors in SharePoint. This is occurring when they just connect to the actual SharePoint site. Internet Explorer is just displaying a generic error message but I captured a more detailed error through Fiddler. The result was this:

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

The user can either wait a few minutes or refresh the page a few times then everything will function normally again. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are your SharePoint server's part of a server farm?  If so, could they be hitting a server that is having ussues?  This could be the reason for getting a valid response after refreshes and the fact that it is only effecting a few users.

Comment: Yes, they are part of a server farm. There are 3 web servers in total. The 1 server is an application server and the other 2 are the front-end web servers. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Do you have the ability to hit each server separately?  That would be the quickest way to rule out that issue.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP 504` is [Gateway Timeout](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.5):

> The server, while acting as a gateway
>   or proxy, did not receive a timely
>   response from the upstream server
>   specified by the URI (e.g. HTTP, FTP,
>   LDAP) or some other auxiliary server
>   (e.g. DNS) it needed to access in
>   attempting to complete the request.

Looks like a connectivity problem to me, probably DNS. Nothing to do with the software. You might have better luck on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).